# Why can I implicitly convert an int literal to an int * in C but not in C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting

I believed that in the following code, C "automatically casts 17 to an `int *`" which, as someone recently pointed out (but did not give the reasons as to why), is wrong.

```
int *ptoi = 17; // I assumed that 17 is being automatically casted to int *
```

I know that if I do the same thing as above in C++, I get an error saying `invalid conversion from int to int *`. But if I do the following in C++, it works fine:

```
int *ptoi = (int *)17;
```

These are the reasons I thought that in C, the casting was implicit.

Can someone please explain why, in C++, I have to cast it but in C, it works fine?

Comment: +1 for a question that legitimately uses both the C and C++ tags ;-)

Comment: I'm guessing C++ does stricter type checking. The cast in C shouldn't give you a pointer that points to the "17". It's a pointer with the value "17" (that points to the "memory address" 17). As a workaround I think you can always cast to a `void*` and then to some other pointer type.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  C++ is stricter than C in many respects, one of which is implicit conversions from one type to another.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Conversions from integers to pointers without casts are also illegal in C.  Most compilers will let you get away with it though.  Clang gives a warning:

```
example.c:5:8: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing
      'int *' with an expression of type 'int'
  int *x = 17;
       ^   ~~
```

C99 says in **Section 6.5.4 Cast operators**, paragraph 4:

> Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast.

6.5.16.1 is the exception for `void *` converting to other pointers without needing a cast.

The C++ spec says in **Section 5.4 Explicit type conversion (cast notation)**, paragraph 3:

> Any type conversion not mentioned below and not explicitly defined by the user is ill-formed.

So there you go - illegal in both languages, but for compatibility with lots of older software, a lot of C compilers will let you get away with it.

Comment: "Conversions from integers to pointers without casts are also illegal in C."  Not according to 6.3.2.3/5: "An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
 result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.56)"  In short, the result may not be meaningful, but it's certainly not *illegal*.

Comment: @JohnBode, to be legal it requires an explicit cast, as mentioned in my quotation above.  It's certainly legal to do `int *x = (int *)17`.

Comment: @JohnBode 6.3.2.3(5) is talking about the result of the conversion, but that's not the question here. 6.5.16.1(1) talks about which implicit conversions are permissible in an assignment operation. The only case which permits the left operand to be pointer type and the right operand to be an integer is case 5, and the restriction is that the right operand be a null pointer constant, which 17 is not. 6.5.4(3) says "Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, *shall be specified by means of a cast*."

Comment: @Raymond - yeah, after reading 6.5.16.1(1), I realize you can't *assign* an integer to a pointer without a cast.

Comment: @mtahmed "now I will rub this answer in that guy's face!" -- totally the wrong inference. 'C "automatically casts 17 to an int *"' is indeed wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the casting is implicit in C, although many (all?) compilers give a warning. In C++, no implicit conversion is performed from `int` to `int*`, so the explicit cast is required.

Answer (score 2):

It has been, C has implicit conversions - in my experience pretty much from any integral type to any other integral type. Pointers in C are <strike>considered integral</strike>*`scalar`* types.

In C++, Integral Types are defined as follows:

> Types `bool`, `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, and the `signed` and `unsigned` integer types are collectively
>   called integral types.<sup>48</sup> A synonym for integral type is integer type. The representations of integral types
>   shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system.<sup>49</sup> [ Example: this International Standard
>   permits 2’s complement, 1’s complement and signed magnitude representations for integral types. —end
>   example ]

The only integral value that can be converted to pointer type in C++ is the *null pointer constant*, though technically the conversion is to a `prvalue` of type `std::nullptr_t`. (para 4.10)

**Final Note**

Instead of fixing it like this:

```
int *ptoi = (int *)17;
```

considering adding the C++-style cast:

```
int *ptoi = reinterpret_cast<int*>(17);
```

to make it clear what kind of conversion you are trying to invoke

Comment: Personally I never saw the benefit of `reinterpret_cast<int*>` over `(int*)`. Just more typing.

Comment: Pointers are not integer types in C99.  Integers are arithmetic types, and both arithmetic & pointer types are *scalar* types, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @CarlNorum: thanks Carl, I don't have a copy of the C99 standard hndy; will amend my post.

Comment: There really isn't any ambiguity in this case. If searching for reinterpretation casts is so important, you could add a `// reinterpretion cast` comment. That's not to say C++-style casts aren't a good thing -- there are certainly important use cases.

Comment: "So now you are proposing to add a comment" -- no, what I'm saying is that searchability is a lousy basis for adding a language feature; reinterpret_cast should stand or fall on its semantics. I'm saying that there is no real need to search for instances of assigning integers to pointer variables ... it's an ad hoc justification.

Comment: @sehe You said it summed up your thoughts. And I already said "there are certainly important use cases". As for assuming that silence means agreement -- that's fallacious. Anyway, this quibble is not worth any more of my time.

Comment: @sehe I assumed nothing ... you EXPLICITLY said that your link reflected your views. Sheesh.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will interpret `int *ptoi = 17;` as a variable ptoi that points to an integer at location 17 (0x00000011).

C is simply a completely different language. It may look like C++, but it's not. Different rules apply to both languages.

I should probably point out that both C and C++ will (as far as I know) make it a pointer to 0x00000011, but C simply complains less, since assigning memory locations is something that's not invalid in C.

Comment: Not quite right: the compiler will interpret `int *ptoi = 17;` as a variable `ptoi` that *points to* an integer stored in memory location 17.

Comment: Ugh, I always get those confused when I write them down here on SO. Fixed!

Comment: 'C is simply a completely different language' -- That's an overstatement. Please see Bjarne Stroustrup's http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#C-is-subset

Comment: 'since assigning memory locations is something that's not invalid in C' -- it's no more or less invalid in C++; the latter simply requires an explicit cast.