# Why is it better to use cast when you assign an integer to a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Let's assume I have this code:

```
  char *pointer;
  unsigned int a;
  pointer = a;
```

For me this doesn't generate any problems but I will receive the following warning:

```
assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Why is it better to use cast? 
I'm using a 32 bit machine.

Edit:
By "this doesn't generate any problems", I was saying that it compiles and pointer stores the value of variable `a`.

Edit: 
And variable `a` will actually store an address.

Comment: Storing one type of pointer into another is odd, so adding the cast makes it clear that's what you were intending.

Comment: Could you tell as what exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need to assign `a` into `pointer` ?

Comment: You should clarify your question by expanding on what you mean by “For me this doesn't generate any problems”.

Comment: Oh I didn't even realize `a` was an int, not int *, making this operation even more strange.

Comment: @PascalCuoq The program compiles and the pointer variable stores the corect value

Comment: @StoicaDan But pointers are for dereferencing, and incidentally for doing pointer arithmetic (only + and -, with serious—if still mostly theoretical—limitations about not going out the pointed object). Integers are for doing arithmetic, bitwise, etc. operations. Why would you store one in a variable of the other type? What utility does storing an address in `a` or an integer in `pointer` have?

Comment: "*And variable `a` will actually store an address.*" -- How can you guarantee this? On some systems, it's impossible for an `int` object to store an address.

Comment: @KeithThompson Maybe is my mistake that I wrote the code that way. Actually in the code I'm working on it's a function with a as parameter. Something like this: function(unsigned int a, unsigned int length, unsigned int * buffer). "pointer" is a char* local variable

Comment: That doesn't really change anything.

Comment: @KeithThompson What I thought in the first place. Why can it be impossible for an int to store an address? And something else, I actually don't understand very well what this guy is trying to do so that's why I can't give you more details - I would better delete this question.

Comment: On 64-bit systems, pointers usually have 64 bits, but `int` only 32. Maybe look for `intptr_t`/`uintptr_t` from `<stdint.h>`. And I guess, you've got more details than just these three lines of code. I think this question is already covered somewhere here on SO, but that aside, there's nothing wrong with it (if it had a clearer description of the problem).

Comment: @StoicaDan: As I mentioned, I'm typing this on a machine with 32-bit `int`s and 64-bit pointers, which is quite common. In that case, you can't store a pointer in an `int` without losing information. There's are integer types `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`, declared in `<stdint.h>`, that can store converted pointers (if those types exist). I wouldn't necessary delete the question; there's some good information in some of the answers.

Comment: It would help if you'd include a *small* working program in the question rather than just a 3-line snippet that doesn't really do anything. And can't you ask the author of the code what it's supposed to do? There just might be a legitimate reason for it.

Answer (score 10):

It's almost always better not to try to assign an integer value to a pointer *at all*. In the rare cases where such an assignment makes sense, a cast is not just better, it's required.

Pointers and integers are distinct types. In some cases it can make sense to mix them; in such cases you need a cast, because there is no implicit conversion between integers and pointers (other than the special case of `0`, treated as a null pointer constant).

```
char *pointer;
int a;         /* or unsigned int a, it's the same either way */
pointer = a;
```

This assignment is illegal (more precisely, a *constraint violation*). A conforming C compiler must at least warn about it. Many compilers, after printing a warning, will generate code that performs an implicit conversion, but that's not required by the language, and you shouldn't depend on it. My personal opinion is that compilers that do this aren't doing you any favors.

```
pointer = (char*)a;
```

This is legal; the cast tells the compiler to generate an conversion from `int` to `char*`. But the result of that conversion is implementation-defined, and very likely doesn't yield a meaningful result -- even if `char*` and `int` happen to be the same size.

(In the code in your question, `a` hasn't been initialized. I presume that's not the case in the real code you haven't shown us.)

What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually I'm testing someone else's code. He wants to be able to enter an address from the keyboard and store it into a pointer.

Comment: @StoicaDan: It rarely make sense to do that; that's why the language doesn't allow you to do it directly. In the rare cases where it makes sense, you can use a cast. The cast says, in effect, "Shut up, compiler, I actually know what I'm doing". What does this code do with the resulting pointer?

Comment: @StoicaDan: For the rare cases where you want to get addresses from the user, you may want to use `sscanf` with `%p`.

Comment: @mafso: A good thought, but it requires the user to know the implementation-defined format recognized by `sscanf`. The behavior of the `%p` conversion is defined *only* if "the input item is a value converted earlier during the same program execution" *(N1570 7.21.6.2); otherwise the behavior is undefined. There is no portable way to detect or handle input errors.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned the risks. But I can't think of any use of integer-to-pointer conversion in portable code, so you already stick to a certain platform when doing so. The format is at least the same as with `printf` for `%p`. And you face the same problems with input checking when using integer types. Anyway, I just felt OP might be interested in `%p` for `sscanf`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The same issue comes up with reading it as an integer then casting. There's no reason to believe that you could use this method to inspect or modify any objects whose addresses you did not previously output in some form.

Comment: @R..: The standard specifically says that the behavior of `*scanf()` with `%p` is undefined unless the input item was previously converted by `*printf` with `%p` during the same program execution; converting an arbitrary integer to a pointer merely yields an implementation-defined result. But yes, in practice you're right; the actual behavior for any real-world implementation is likely to be reasonably sane. The biggest difference is that the format produced or consumed by `%p` is entirely implementation-defined; an implementation might use octal and not recognize hex, or vice versa.

Comment: My point was that (by the as-if rule) there's no way you can expect an object whose address was not ever taken to even have a meaningful address, and even an object whose address was taken might move to a different address (again, by the as-if rule) as long as the program cannot observe that this has happened.

Answer (score 6):

Because in C:

```
pointer = a;  // not valid in C: a is an int object
              // pointer an object of pointer type
```

the statement is not valid, you need an explicit conversion (a cast) to convert `a` value to a pointer type.

```
pointer = (char *) a;  // valid assignmnent
```

Some compilers are nice with you and will implicitly convert the `int` value to a pointer type (and add a warning!) but they are not required to do so and a compiler can refuse to compile your program.

Comment: Nice answer by the standard, but looking at it "objectively", it's like your kid asking you 'why is it not allowed', and you answer 'because it's prohibited'.

Comment: @MatteoItalia well no, in C, why?

Comment: @barakmanos Maybe it's because you assume the reader already knows that assigning an integer value to an object of pointer type is not valid.

Comment: Well, "not allowed", "not valid"... It all sounds the same. I believe that there's a reason behind this warning (not just because it's "not allowed") - these two types are not necessarily the same size on every platform.

Comment: @barakmanos the reason behind the warning is there is a constraint violation of the assignment operator and that a constraint violation requires at least a diagnostic message from the compiler.

Comment: So it's got nothing to do with the fact that the standard does not strictly define `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(void*)` to the same value?

Comment: @barakmanos Moreover *Well, "not allowed", "not valid"... It all sounds the same.* OP does not asks why it it is not allowed, he asks why it is better. And my answer is simple, it is not better, one of the form is simply invalid code.

Comment: I understand that, but it appears that people here often try to "stick" their answers to **what** the standard says, and not to **why** it says it. Sometimes there is indeed no reason to explain or elaborate. But in this case, basic logic of where the question stems from, would suggest that OP does not understand the risk being taken with this (unsafe) assignment.

Comment: @barakmanos *"two types are not necessarily the same size on every platform"* I don't think it is the rationale for the assignment constraint in the Standard. Look, you can assign any integer type of different size to any integer type of another size (for example from `unsigned long long` to `unsigned char`). In this case, one type is an integer type and the other type is a pointer type. C probably forbids the assignments because C is a typed language and typed languages tend to limit the number of implicit conversions.

Comment: @ouah: IIRC in C implicit conversion from `int` to pointer is allowed (and it bit me several times in the past), while in C++ is actually an error. I didn't check the standard, but both `gcc` and `clang` give me a strong warning when doing it in C, and an error in C++ (http://pastebin.com/FQhr9gQu).

Comment: @MatteoItalia *IIRC in C implicit conversion from int to pointer is allowed* It is not allowed, constraints of the assignment operator are violated (see 6.5.16.1p1 in c11).

Comment: @ouah: what about implicit conversions (§6.3.2.3 ¶5)? Don't they come in play before, making the int decay to pointer before assignment/initialization?

Comment: Ok, my bad, found the relevant standard quotation (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8288548/214671).

Comment: @MatteoItalia yes 6.3.2.3p5 is used for the cast of an integer value to a pointer type.

Comment: A quibble: IMHO there's nothing "nice" about permitting invalid implicit conversions. (It's usually done to avoid breaking old code.)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: There is no implicit conversion from integer types to pointer types (apart from the special case of `0` treated as a null pointer constant). Unfortunately, many compilers permit such implicit conversions (which is legal as long as they issue a warning) as a concession to old code.

Answer (score 3):

```
% cat int-cast.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof char *: %zu\n", sizeof (char *));
    printf("sizeof int: %zu\n", sizeof (int));
}
```

Then if compiled 32 or 64 bit the size of the types differ

`% cc -m32 int-cast.c && ./a.out 
sizeof char *: 4
sizeof int: 4
% cc -m64 int-cast.c && ./a.out 
sizeof char *: 8
sizeof int: 4`

And as Keith Thompson explicitly points out, even if they were guaranteed to be the same size, a cast would still be required, and the result would be at best implementation-defined.

Comment: The two types may have different sizes, OK, but how using a cast will make a difference in the assignment bevahior? (It was OP actual question.)

Comment: I was just showing one reason why the compiler would require an explicit cast - I think other answers below (yours included) do a better job of explaining the casting (and why it probably isn't a good idea).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The assignment is invalid, but not because of the sizes of `int` and `char*`; even if they were guaranteed to be the same size, a cast would still be required, and the result would be at best implementation-defined. Furthermore, `void main(void)` should be `int main(void)`, `#include <sys/types.h>` is non-portable and unnecessary, and the correct format for printing a `size_t` value is `%zu`, not `%d`.

Comment: Updated based on Keith's feedback (and now that I have sufficient reputation, an upvote for Keith's answer which answers it best for me)

Answer (score 0):

In C a pointer is not only an address in memory, it is also a type:

```
pointer = memory size + type
```

The best way to understand this is to think about pointer arithmetic that prevent to do some arithmetics operations. For example, you can do:

```
int i;
int * ptr, ptr2;

ptr = &i;  // Assign the address of an int to an int pointer
ptr2 = ptr + 2; // Shift the pointer of two int size further
i = ptr - ptr2; // Compute the number of slots between ptr and ptr2
```

But, you cannot do:

```
int i;
char c;
int * ptr;
char * ptr2;

ptr = &c; // The types are not matching, the compiler will complain 
ptr = 2 * ptr; // This is not allowed by pointer arithmetic
ptr = ptr + ptr; // This is not allowed by pointer arithmetic
```

And so on...

But, what you have always to remember is that a pointer is not only a memory address. It is the combination of a memory address **and** a type.

Comment: Incidentally, `ptr2 = ptr + 2;` in your first example invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Well, it is undefined in the sense of the execution. But, this is perfectly defined in the sense of the semantics. But, yes, I agree with you.

Comment: @perror: What distinction are you making between execution and semantics? `ptr2 = ptr + 2` does have well defined behavior *if* `ptr` contains the address of an array element and there's at least one element immediately following it. The *semantics* of pointer addition are: yield a specified value if certain requirements are meant, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I make a distinction between semantics and execution because `ptr2 = ptr + 2;` has a semantics, but it will give an undefined behavior at execution time. For example, if you consider this line: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i++){printf("%d", i);}` the `i=i++` does not have a well-defined semantics (and, thus the compiler will take a choice on its own and give an unpredictable behaviour again... but for semantical reason).

Comment: @perror: Ok -- but I'm not convinced that's a useful distinction

Comment: Yes, it is useful if you are building static analyzer (an undefined in the semantics is really a pain, and a bug is just a bug). :-)