# Invalid operands to binary + (char*) and (char*)?

Tags: c

Why doesn't this code just print the two strings? I'm casting 5 to (char *) so what am I doing wrong?

```
int *p = 5;
char * str = "msg";
printf("string is: %s" + "%s", str, (char *) p);
```

Comment: Because `p` is pointing to the *address* `5`, and it's unlikely there's a valid string at that address.

Comment: Remove the line numbers from the code. Your code is unlikely to compile. Also it must have some warning!

Comment: There's also the problem that C doesn't have an operator `+` for strings literals.

Comment: `"string is: %s" + "%s"` --> `"string is: %s %s"`

Comment: @delnan It's a valid definition and initialization, it just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @delnan should it be int* p = (int *) 5?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Now that I tried it out... damn. You wouldn't happen to know *why* this is legal? As you say, it doesn't make sense, and nothing of that sort *ever* makes sense with the exception of a constant 0 (which is special cased anyway).

Comment: @delnan Because an address in a computer is an integer number. And if the size of `int` happens to be the same as the size of an address (like e.g. a 32-bit system) then any integer value is considered a valid address. And as everyone should know, a pointer variable is just an integer variable containing the address of what the pointer points to.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  with this change, I get fault.

Comment: @Stochastic13 You might, by the way, want to read about [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Because if you fix the problem pointed out by BLUEPIXY then undefined behavior is what you have.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Nonsense. An address may be a number to the hardware, but a pointer in C is a separate type from integers. Someone, somewhere allowed implicit conversions from integer types (or just integer constants?) to pointer types, which seems silly because such a conversion is almost never meaningful outside of 0, even though there is no problem with *implementing* it.

Comment: @Stochastic13 Probably, the Address 5 is forbidden read by OS.

Comment: Oh, and you have another source of undefined behavior in the initialization of `str`, because string literals are arrays of *constant* (i.e. read-only) characters, so having a pointer to non-constant character and then assign it to point to a string literal will cause undefined behavior if you try to modify the string.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY even when I do int *p = (int *) 5; I still get seg fault.

Comment: @Stochastic13 It refers to Address 5 Again.

Comment: @delnan In C an `int` can be implicitly converted to a pointer. You will most likely get a warning (makes pointer from integer, or similar) but it's still a valid implicit conversion.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I got that the first time around ;-) I was wondering *why* that implicit conversion might have been permitted in the first place, and still around (other relics of very-early-C are slowly being phased out).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Only with explicit cast, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288502. However I guess it's with exception to `0` (integer constant), which is obviously allowed..

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Thank you for finding that. So it's **not** actually permitted, just a stupid compiler extension.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Ah there's a good example of that anyone, even very experienced people, can learn something from this site, even by not asking questions. :)

Comment: `int n = 6579570; int *p = &n;` if x86.

Comment: @delnan For low level hardware access it is _absolutely indispensable_ to read from and/or write to known and ultimately hard coded locations. Newer C standards demand a cast when assigning arithmetic values to pointers and vice versa, however (cf. the exhaustive list at 6.5.16.1 which does not mention such assignments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will give a warning, like:

> main.c:5:12: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer
>   without a cast [enabled by default]

since you try to assign an integer to a pointer without a cast. Even with a cast, it will rarely be what you want, a pointer to the address you gave.

I will provide an example, were I declare a variable `a` initialized with 5 and then, assign its address to a pointer `p`.

Also, notice that C, unlike C++ and Java doesn't provide a `+` operator for strings. You have to use `string.h` library for this kind of operations.

[EDIT] (see comments, thanks to Deduplicator)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int a = 5;
    // Assign the address of 'a' to the pointer 'p'.
    int *p = &a;
    // Now p points to variable 'a', thus 5.
    // The value of 'p' is the address of the variable 'a'.

    char const *str = "msg";

    // print the string 'str' and the number, that 'p'
    // points to. Since `p` is of type `int*`, we expect
    // it to point to an integer, thus we use %d in the
    // printf().
    printf("string is: %s%d", str, *p);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> string is: msg5

Comment: try to assign an integer to a pointer, more like. And it makes sense (cast required), the resultant pointer being implementation-defined (though there's a suggestion it should be consistent with the underlying machines addressing-scheme). Still, that's obviously not what the asker thought it would do, and it is seldom what one would want.

Comment: @Deduplicator would you like me to change my answer somehow? Assigning the integer directly to the pointer is not what one should do.

Comment: Yes. The first is an obvious confusion of what is assigned to what, and the second is not quite right (nit-picking is a high art, and programmers need to be adept in it). Yes, assigning an integer to a pointer is really rare on modern desktops and servers in user-mode, but still useful on embedded systems and in kernel-mode.

Comment: OK, help me improve the answer @Deduplicator. You mean the part with `a` and `p`. I am assigning the address of the variable `a` to pointer `p`. The OP wants to print actually "msg5". I printed "msg, 5". I found this on SO, with 77 votes up. However, I don't like it either, so I am going to edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, no. I'm talking about the paragraph directly following the warning-message you included.

Comment: @Lee You stomped all over G.Samaras changes. Shit happens.

Comment: `char const *str = "msg";` would be preferable