# What happens when I tell printf to print a variable?

Tags: c, printf

When I run the following code (on Eclipse), I get a pop-up message that the .exe has stop working:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    main ()
    {
       int x;
       x = 1;

       printf(x);
    }
```

I know that I should code it as follows in order to make it run:

```
printf("%d", x);
```

However, my question is simply what's going on "in there" when I code it the former way.

Comment: Technically it shouldn't compile, but for some info on why it does, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288502/why-can-i-implicitly-convert-an-int-literal-to-an-int-in-c-but-not-in-c

Comment: It might be a good idea to read `printf()`'s documentation (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sprintf.3.html) prior to using the function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, yet again, seeks an explanation for acknowledged UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf()` first parameter is meant to be a string.

In C, the value '1' is pushed onto the stack to call printf.  printf is expecting a string, so it starts to treat 1 as an address.

This causes the "stops working" - when it tries to look at the characters at address 1.

Comment: Thanks. I have a certain way to go before getting to the addresses section, so I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Your code tells `printf` to print the string at memory address `1`.

You probably can't access that, so it crashes.

Comment: Thanks. I have a certain way to go before getting to the addresses section, so I'll keep that in mind.