# assign hardcoded address to pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am surprised why my compiler is allowing me the hard-coded pointer address? Why is it not crashing? As per my understating, logical address is something selected by compiler.

```
main()
{
    int *p;
    
    p = 10;          // why it is allowed? Ideally, it should be    int a; p = &a;
    
    printf("%u", p);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense on systems with virtual memory, but it does make sense on hardware system with memory mapped IO.

Comment: You should be getting a warning from the compiler. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8288548

Comment: Making the assignment is not a problem, but using it probably will be.  Try `p=10; *p = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

C evolved and was designed for many different purposes. In general-purpose multi-user operating systems, programs run in virtual address spaces, and memory addresses are assigned based on a combination of what the operating system provides, a program-loading scheme, and allocations made through the stack, memory management routines, memory mapping routines, and/or other services.

In special-purpose systems, memory addresses may be assigned manually or may result from hardware requirements. This is one of the purposes C supports.

Even in multi-user operating systems, the system may provide some data at fixed addresses, such as the “common page” in macOS. However, in that case, the addresses are likely supplied to you via definitions in header files, so you would use `int *p = _SomeSymbolFromTheCommonPage;` rather than directly encoding the numeric address yourself.

Compilers will generally warn you about bare assignments of integers to pointers, as in `p = 10;`. Your compiler likely has a switch to treat warnings as errors (`-Werror` for GCC and Clang, `/WX` for MSVC), and it is generally a good idea to enable that and to learn to modify your code to avoid warnings. When you want to deliberately assign a hard-coded address, you can use a cast to indicate it is intentional: `p = (int *) 10;`, and typically a compiler will not issue its integer-to-pointer warning for that.